# Unix script how to extract string from a file

Tags: shell, unix

How to extract the value after the 4th slash (`/`) from `/FTP-Test/TestAutoUpdate/Test/1/x64` ?

The extracted result for the example should be `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'/' '{print $5}' file

kent$  echo "/FTP-Test/TestAutoUpdate/Test/1/x64"|awk -F'/' '{print $5}'
1
```